# Some questions about GWT Basics

Tags: sql, hibernate, google-app-engine, gwt, jpa

I'm new with Google Web Toolkit and i have some questions about the tool.

First of all, what i have to know to correctly program for GWT? It's ok if i use the GWT Designer to make the GUI?

Second, how i persists all the data i want to store? Use JPA/Hibernate + SQL Database? Or it's better to use AppEngine?
I'm with a great doubt how i get the data from Database to populate fields and tables on client-side.

and Last, i know a bit of Swing, so, GWT is the same? (Except Client - Server concept) ?

That's my questions. Well, thanks in advance.

Comment: These are all Google-able questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, what i have to know to correctly program for GWT? It's ok if i use the GWT Designer to make the GUI?

Ok.

> Second, how i persists all the data i want to store? Use JPA/Hibernate + SQL Database? Or it's better to use AppEngine?

It's your choice.  AppEngine has it's limitations.  For example, it scales but may not be the best choice for multi-player games if you need data updated very often and quickly.  It really depends on your need/design.

If you do go with AppEngine, my experience with JPA was a headache.  Objectify is much easier and the way I would go.

> Last, i know a bit of Swing, so, GWT is the same? (Except Client - Server concept) ?

I guess they share the concept of using listeners/handlers for events.  They are not the same though.